# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class

Tags: office365, adal

I am trying to communicate with REST API using ADAL. getting below error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
                at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
                at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
                at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
                at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
                at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
                at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
                at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext.acquireToken(AuthenticationContext.java:382)
                at edu.stanford.test.AccToken.main(AccToken.java:40)
```

---

Code used is :

```
            import java.io.BufferedReader;
            import java.io.FileInputStream;
            import java.io.InputStream;
            import java.io.InputStreamReader;
            import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
            import java.net.URL;
            import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
            import java.util.Date;
            import java.util.UUID;
            import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
            import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
            import java.util.concurrent.Future;

            import com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AsymmetricKeyCredential;
            import com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext;
            import com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationResult;

            public class AcceToken {

                public static void main(String[] args) {

                    String authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant-id/oauth2/authorize";
                    ExecutorService service = null;
                    service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
                    try {
                        AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(
                                authority, false, service);
                        System.out.println("Authentication Context is "+ authenticationContext.getAuthority() );
                        String certfile = "D:\\Microsoft-tools\\Samples\\Final\\test.pfx";
                        InputStream pkcs12Certificate = new FileInputStream(certfile);

                        String token = "";

                        AsymmetricKeyCredential credential = AsymmetricKeyCredential
                                .create("id", pkcs12Certificate, "password");
                        System.out.println("X509 is fine!");

                        Future<AuthenticationResult> future = authenticationContext.acquireToken("https://outlook.office365.com",(AsymmetricKeyCredential) credential, null);

                        token = future.get().getAccessToken();

                        Long uuid = UUID.randomUUID().getMostSignificantBits();

                        URL url = new URL(
                                "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/emailaddress/folders/inbox/messages");
                        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
                        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Testing/1.0 abc/1.1");
                        Date date = new Date();

                        SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat(
                                "E, dd MM yyyy hh:mm:ss zzz");

                        System.out.println("Current Date: " + ft.format(date));
                        String dateString = ft.format(date);

                        con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

                        if (con.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                            System.out.println(con.getHeaderFields());

                            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                                    + con.getResponseCode());

                        }

                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                (con.getInputStream())));

                        String output;
                        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
                        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            System.out.println(output);
                        }

                        con.disconnect();

                        service.shutdown();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

### }

I am getting an error at the line below:

```
Future<AuthenticationResult> future = authenticationContext.acquireToken("https://outlook.office365.com",(AsymmetricKeyCredential) credential, null);
```

when i looked into it i found that in line 382 of AuthenticationContext.java. We are calling buildJwt method of JwtHelper class which is calling AdalJWTClaimsSet class which is extending JWTClaimsSet class.

JWTClaimsSet class is no longer public it is final now.

I tied using earlier version of JWT jars but i keep getting other errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADAL depends on oauth2-oidc-sdk version 4.5 and it depends on nimbus-jose-jwt version 3.1.2. It has JWTClaimsSet class as public. Are you overriding the version of these libraries in your pom.xml? You can try the samples at  https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java/tree/master/src/samples and see adal4j working as expected.

Comment: Thanks Kanishk. Above suggestion resolved the issue.